# How to add a tile dynamically in isometric map in Cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tile, isometric, kobold2d

I have an isometric map made using [Tiled Map editor](http://www.mapeditor.org). Current tile has only a base layer (i.e. the background).

I want to add a tile OVER this layer dynamically, say at tile position (1,1), such that the tile effectively becomes a part of the map.

So when I change the position of the map (e.g. while scrolling) I want the newly added tile to behave like the part of the map and move in its tile position with the map.

I tried CCTMXLayer classes `-(void) addChild: (CCNode*)node z:(NSInteger)z tag:(NSInteger)tag;` but it throws an error saying this. I dont quite understand the 2nd line.

> addchild:z:tag: is not supported on CCTMXLayer. Instead of setTileGID:at:/tileAt:

Also, I tried adding an Object Layer in Tiled and accessed an objects properties -

```
CCTMXObjectGroup* objectLayer=[tileMap objectGroupNamed:@"ObjectLayer"];
NSDictionary *properties = [objectLayer objectNamed:@"theObject"];
int x = [properties[@"x"] intValue];
int y = [properties[@"y"] intValue];
```

Here I'm facing difficulty in converting from the x,y value to screen coordinates. Or from x,y to correct tilePos. Need urgent help here.

Side note - I read the [Kobold Kit](http://koboldkit.com/tiled-tilemap-features/) will have ability to "Create and modify every tilemap aspect at runtime". Will this help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a tile to say tile (x,y) ( (x,y) in Tiled Map editor coordinates ) then use the following code -

myTileMap is the reference to the CCTMXTiledMap object.

```
CCTMXLayer *layer=[myTileMap layerNamed:@"yourlayer"];
NSAssert(floorLayer !=nil, @"Ground layer not found!");    
CGPoint tileAddPosition = [layer positionAt: CGPointMake(x,y)];

//Create your CCNode or CCSprite or whatever...say object name is **tileToBeAdded**

tileToBeAdded.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
tileToBeAdded.position = tileAddPosition;
[myTileMap addChild:addedTile z:1];
```